# How do I order a Group by and Order by a result using Linq

Tags: linq, group-by, sql-order-by

I have datetime values (e.g. 12/01/2010 10:10:222..)  How can I display just the year in desc order?  For example, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, etc.. I need to group by just the year part of the field and return that.  I actually need to return the year and the name.  I need to use the name for other functionality, which is why I need the 2 values.

Thanks for any help...

Comment: What do you mean by "return the year and the name"? What if multiple entries have the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean, but you *might* just want something like:

```
var query = collection.GroupBy(record => record.DateProperty.Year)
                      .OrderBy(group => group.Key);
```

If that's not what you're after, please provide more details - ideally some sample input and desired output.

If you only want one entry from each group and you're happy to take any arbitrary one to get the name, and you only want the year, you could do:

```
var query = collection.GroupBy(record => record.DateProperty.Year)
                      .Select(g => new { Year = g.Key, Name = g.First().Name })
                      .OrderBy(x => x.Year);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the Distinct and OrderByDescending extensions:

```
var years = IQueryableObject
                 .Distinct(x => x.Year).OrderByDescending(x => x.Year).ToList();
```

Comment: Distinct doesn't take an argument saying what to make it distinct by, so this won't compile.

Comment: This worked for me:  var sortedList = (from p in newsPressReleaseGenericList
orderby p.ReleaseDate.Year descending
select new { ReleaseDate = p.ReleaseDate.Year }).Distinct();